# reading structs in C?

Tags: c, file, struct, io, fread

So i have a struct book,

```
struct book
{
  unsigned short  content_size;
  unsigned short  price;
  unsigned char  *content;
};
```

And a input file that contains 5 books with content like this, but binary form in actual file:

> content_size: 64    price: 33
>
> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
>
> content_size: 16    price: 21
>
> bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
>
> content_size: 16    price: 22
>
> cccccccccccccccc
>
> content_size: 32    price: 10
>
> dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
>
> content_size: 32    price: 8
>
> eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

However, I got the following output:

> read a book, size is: 64
>
> read a book, size is: 24929
>
> read a book, size is: 24929
>
> read a book, size is: 24929
>
> read a book, size is: 24929
>
> read a book, size is: 16
>
> read a book, size is: 25186
>
> read a book, size is: 16
>
> read a book, size is: 25443
>
> read a book, size is: 32
>
> read a book, size is: 25700
>
> read a book, size is: 25700
>
> read a book, size is: 32
>
> read a book, size is: 25957
>
> read a book, size is: 25957

What are those big numbers and why am I reading them? Thanks!

Comment: In your struct, `content` is a pointer. In the file, it's a string. You need to read the string into a new block of memory, then set the pointer to point to it.

Comment: You'll have to read field by field.  The length field will tell you how large a buffer to malloc for content and then read that.

Comment: what do you mean by field by field? @Duck

Answer (score 2):

```
size_t nread;
struct book book1;

while ((nread = fread(&book1.content_size, sizeof book1.content_size, 1, infp)) > 0) {
    fread(&book1.price, sizeof book1.price, 1, infp);
    book1.content = malloc(book1.content_size+1);
    fread(book1.content, 1, book1.content_size, infp);
    book1.content[book1.content_size] = '\0';
    printf("read a book, size is %d, price is %d, content is %s\n", book1.content_size, book1.price, book1.content);
    free(book1.content);
}
```

Comment: Quick security comment: I know it is demonstration code but you've trusted the length of the content_size field. If it is set to 0xffff you just malloc'd 0 bytes then wrote all over random bits of memory. Best to validate all external data, use an if to limit it to 1024 or some reasonable value.

Comment: It would help to see the code that writes the file. We need to know how the fields are actually laid out in its binary structure.

Comment: hmm, thanks a lot though! Also I see you indicate the size of book1.content to 1 when reading it, is that a typo?

Comment: No, because I set the number of elements to read as `book1.content_size`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `struct packet` is `struct book` am I wrong ? I not then you have problems with your code. The structure contains a `char *` a pointer, and you can't read a pointer from file without a problem. I suspect that you would like to read the sequences of 'a' of 'b' and get a `char *` from that read. But you can't do it like this. You should read the "string" like this :

```
char t[MAX];
l=fread(t,sizeof(char),length,yourfilehandler)
yourBook->content = malloc(l+1);
memcpy(yourBook->content,t,l);
yourBook->content[l] = '\0';
```

The problem is to determine the value of `length`, as you didn't specified well how the file is organized we cannot answer (you mentionned that the file is in binary format, but which one ?)

Comment: Looks like `content_size` is the length.

Comment: what if there is not pointer in my struct? How do i read it one struct at a time then?

Comment: if no pointer then `struct whatever {...};` can be safely read by `struct whatever w; fread(&w,sizeof(w),1,file);`